# What is a mild form of "idiot" that might be used by a German-speaking Czech?

Tags: colloquial, regional, insult

I need advice picking a mild insult a character I'm writing might blurt out when irritated at another. The character is an ethnic German from Czechia, woman speaking to a male friend. The obvious one is *Dummkopf* but since profanity and insults tend to be fairly regional, I was wondering if there was a more local one I could use.

I did some googling and found a couple that I liked: *Pappnase* seems like it might have the right feel.

Comment: Try _Dummerle_ or _Blondie_ maybe. These still leave room for humor.

Comment: Pappnase, yep, that's a clown. I was named so today :-). "Du Dubbel(chen)". If you want to transport a feel, tell us the situation, because there tons of ways, tailored or general ...

Comment: I have never heard neither Dubbel nor Dubbelchen.

Comment: There's likely a certain influence of Austrian/Bavarian on the German spoken in Czechia, at least in the south and in Prager Deutsch (if that's still a thing), but I'm really not familiar with the linguistic situation. If you embrace that, there's a lot of Austrian vocabulary you can choose from.

Comment: I mean, you could listen to Karl Schwarzenberg interviews/talks until he says something suitable (he was raised in Austria).

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. What do you mean by "more local"? local = german ethnic in Czechia or "local = german mothertongue"? Sudetendeutsch? Deutschböhmer? https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Minderheit_in_Tschechien

Answer (score 1):

**Blödian**

I like "Pappnase" a lot, but not to *blurt out* in irritation.

The adjective "blöd" is heavily used in Hasek's Schweijk; a running gag is his triumphant confirmation after somebody calls him "Idiot" or "Blödian", or asks him: "Schweijk, sind Sie eigentlich blöd?" -- "I can't help it, ...

> ... man hat mich beim Militär wegen **Blödheit** superarbitriert. Ich
>   bin amtlich von der Superarbitrierungskommission für einen Idioten
>   erklärt worden."

Like "Idiotie", "Blödheit" was/is a medico-legal term. I googled for Schweijk citation but found a German wikipedia article on "Blödheit".

---

"Blödes Wetter!" you can easily say, but "Idiotisches Wetter!" is exaggerated.

The "**-ian**" ending also does some softening. I can only recommend this word for a general mild insult.

---

I recently saw a young local comedian on his poster, with his show titled:

> HALBIDIOT

And him pressing the mic to his *ear*, staring at you with his mouth half open. I don't think you can call this guy a "Idiot" or even "Blödian". Maybe even "VOLLIDIOT" would work, paradoxically.

wikipedia also cites Th. Fontane's Effi Briest:

> sie [not Effi I hope...] war damenhafter als die beiden anderen, dafür aber **langweilig** und
>   **eingebildet**, eine lymphatische **Blondine**, mit etwas vorspringenden,
>   **blöden Augen, die trotzdem** beständig nach was zu suchen schienen,
>   weshalb denn auch Klitzing von den Husaren gesagt hatte: „Sieht sie
>   nicht aus, als erwarte sie jeden Augenblick den Engel Gabriel?

He also looks very expecting, and is expecting the impossible, too:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions for words a woman might use to mildly insult (or tease) a male friend:

(This is a community wiki. Everybody can extend the list)

- du Bimbo (same problem as with Mongo)
- du Blödel / du Blödian
- du Doofi / du Doofkopp
- du Dummerchen / du Dummerle
- du Hirni
- du Kasper / du Kaschperl
- du Mongo (this is not politically correct; but it is in use)
- du Obergenie
- du Schlaule / Schlauchen / Schlauberger / Schlaumeier (ironic use!)
- du Trottelchen

Note 1: each of them carries a certain attitude which to explain would take quite some time and effort, and of course it depends very much on the situation where the word is used, the pronunciation, facial expressions et cetera...

Note 2: I do not see in what way a German-speaking Czech would have a different vocabulary than a German-speaking Non-Czech. You can, of course, let your characters speak German with a typical Czech accent, but that's a mere issue of pronunciation.

Comment: Ich kenne Bimbo nur in der Version, die sich wohl am ehesten mit Flittchen gleichsetzen lässt. Finde ich in der oben beschriebenen Konstellation eher ungewöhnlich.

Comment: @infinitezero   Meine Referenzregion für den Gebrauch von *Bimbo* ist Südwestdeutschland. Von dort kenne ich das nur in der Bedeutung "dummer, nicht ernst zu nehmender Mensch". Mir ist aber bewusst, dass es in anderen Teilen des deutschsprachigen Gebiets (und ich vermute v.a. auch im englischsprachigen Gebiet) eine aufs Sexuelle reduzierte Person meint oder meinen kann. Diese Verwendung von *Bimbo* ist mir selbst jedoch völlig fremd.

Comment: Ex Reig'schmeckter hier: Bimbo und Mongo habe ich in Stuttgart/Tübingen/Karlsruhe und Umgebung in >20Jahren nie gehört in dem Zusammenhang, was wohl eher an meinem Umgang liegt. Ersteren würde ich auch vermeiden, wurde ja schon gesagt.

Comment: "Bimbo" ist ambivalent, ich rate von der Verwendung ab. Die Verwendung wie in obiger Antwort ist mir aus dem amerikanischen Englisch bekannt,vgl. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bimbo_(englischer_Slang): *Das Lehnwort aus dem Italienischen bezeichnet heute eine meist attraktive, aber einfältige Frau. Im Deutschen kann man den Ausdruck mit „Tussi“ oder „dummes Blondchen“ übersetzen.* Allerdings ist es auch eine abwertende Bezeichnung für Personen mit dunkler Hautfarbe, vgl. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bimbo.

Comment: Wie wäre es mit mit dem hessischen "Dappes"? Vgl. https://www.fnp.de/kolumnen/hessisch-anfaenger-10777010.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe ''Pappnase'' could correctly translate "gonzo" (which can mean "nose" in German, but also other appendages, if you know what I mean). That's not even mild.

A sole ''du Nase'' would suffice.